# Column vector notation as "ordered set notation"

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

AFAIK, a vector can be specified using either "ordered set notation" or "matrix notation"

**Ordered set notation**

[image]

**Matrix notation of row and colum vectors**

[image]

I wonder if a column vector can be specified using ordered set notation. For example, can a column vector

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$$ be specified as follows?
$$(1,2,3)$$

Plus, is the following statement correct?

> A set {(1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,0,1)} is a basis of column space of the matrix
>
> \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&1&1\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.

Comment: Yep. Why do you think not?

Comment: Some write $(1\;2 \;3)^T$ for $\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}$

Comment: In the context of vectors & matrices, I always interpret $(1,2,3)$ as a column vector. It's a way to write a column vector without leaving lots of white space on the page.

Comment: My TA said I should've specified the basis vectors as $${{(1,0,0)^T,(1,1,0)^T,(1,0,1)^T}}$$, which I think is non-sense because it is a mix of two notation methods.

Comment: @Gerry_Myerson But how do you write row vectors, then?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin A row vector can be written as $(1\ 2\ 3)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the column vector $\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
2\\
3
\end{bmatrix}$ and the ordered set $(1,2,3)$ represent the same element of the same **linear space**.

However, AFAIK, a set can't be seen as a basis minor of a matrix just because of [the determinant minor definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)).